# How to `reduce` only within partitions in Spark Streaming, perhaps using combineByKey?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, redis, spark-streaming, partitioning

I have data already sorted by key into my Spark Streaming partitions by virtue of Kafka, i.e. keys found on one node are not found on any other nodes.

I would like to use redis and its `incrby` (increment by) command as a state engine and to reduce the number of requests sent to redis, I would like to partially reduce my data by doing a word count on each worker node by itself. (The key is tag+timestamp to obtain my functionality from word count).
I would like to avoid shuffling and let redis take care of adding data across worker nodes.

Even when I have checked that data is cleanly split among worker nodes, `.reduce(_ + _)` (Scala syntax) takes a long time (several seconds vs. sub-second for map tasks), as the HashPartitioner seems to shuffle my data to a random node to add it there.

How can I write a simple word count reduce on each partitioner without triggering the shuffling step in Scala with Spark Streaming?

Note DStream objects lack some RDD methods, which are available only through the `transform` method.

It seems I might be able to use `combineByKey`. I would like to skip the `mergeCombiners()` step and instead leave accumulated tuples where they are.
The book "Learning Spark" enigmatically says:

> We can disable map-side aggregation in combineByKey() if we know that our data won’t benefit from it. For example, groupByKey() disables map-side aggregation as the aggregation function (appending to a list) does not save any space. If we want to disable map-side combines, we need to specify the partitioner; for now you can just use the partitioner on the source RDD by passing rdd.partitioner.

https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/learning-spark/9781449359034/ch04.html

The book then continues to supply no syntax for how to do this, nor have I had any luck with google so far.

What is worse, as far as I know, the partitioner is not set for DStream RDDs in Spark Streaming, so I don't know how to supply a partitioner to combineByKey that doesn't end up shuffling data.

Also, what does "map-side" actually mean and what consequences does `mapSideCombine = false` have, exactly?

The scala implementation for `combineByKey` can be found at
https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/PairRDDFunctions.scala
Look for `combineByKeyWithClassTag`.

If the solution involves a custom partitioner, please include also a code sample for how to apply that partitioner to the incoming DStream.

Comment: When a `DStream` is read from Kafka, there is a 1:1 correspondents between Kafka partitions and Spark partitions. But, there is no guarantee that the same worker node will always read the same partition, which means that there is no guarantee that all your keys will end up on a single spark worker node. Thus, you do need to shuffle data.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I am planning to use redis and its increment-by `incrby` command as a state engine, so this would not be a problem, it would still help reduce the messages sent to redis if I could reduce only what is on each worker node. How can I do that?

Answer (score 5):

This can be done using `mapPartitions`, which takes a function that maps an iterator of the input RDD on one partition to an iterator over the output RDD.

To implement a word count, I map to `_._2` to remove the Kafka key and then perform a fast iterator word count using `foldLeft`, initializing a `mutable.hashMap`, which then gets converted to an Iterator to form the output RDD.

```
val myDstream = messages
  .mapPartitions( it =>
    it.map(_._2)
    .foldLeft(new mutable.HashMap[String, Int])(
      (count, key) => count += (key -> (count.getOrElse(key, 0) + 1))
    ).toIterator
  )
```